# Portable TexLive XeLaTeX work in XeTeX mode under WinXp

Tags: xetex, texlive

My `XeLaTeX` work in `plain XeTeX` mode. When I try to compile some file with LaTeX format, I get  `Undefined control sequence. \documentclass`.

TexStudio tabs:
[image]
[image]

Files in the folder:

[image]

`XeLaTex` say that is a `XeTeX`

[image]

XeLaTeX

Comment: Use `xelatex myfile` instead of `xetex myfile`

Comment: @karlkoeller of cource, I use xelatex myfile, Otherwise I would not write about the problem.

Comment: Try running `fmtutil-sys --all` to rebuild the formats.

Comment: Have you solved?

Comment: @karlkoeller, unfortunately, not,  rebuildind formats has no effect

Comment: Anyway, `preloaded format=xelatex` means you are running `xelatex`

Comment: @karlkoeller yes, of course, but my output means I running xetex.

Comment: What about Latex and lualatex? Did you check the log-files of the format creation? Did fmtutil rebuild the format used by the compilation?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer the same thing. I rebuild format